# How can I reference/call a cell in another worksheet that is a subtotal of a column that has a dynamically changing number of rows and

Tags: excel

and...is populated by data coming from an external system? The problem is that the row has no other label or indentifier to reference. It will however, always be in the same column, but could be on line X one day and line Y the other.

Comment: Use the `Find` function and search within formulas for the word `Subtotal` or something similar...

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment, since you know there will be a subtotal function in this column, you could use the `Find()` method and look for the word "SUBTOTAL" as follows:

```
Dim myCell As Range
Set myCell = OtherSheet.Range("E:E").Find(what:="SUBTOTAL", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

This will set `myCell` to the first cell in that column that has the SubTotal formula within it (obviously, change the `Range("E:E")` reference to your desired column.

Hope that does the trick!!